# Uploading an image file to GAE datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, upload

Im trying to upload an image file to the GAE datastore using jQuery within CoffeScript.

The upload jQuery Post function I'm using is:

```
$.post "/uploadBTS?bts_spriteSheet=#{@bts_spritesheet_url}", (data) =>
      console.log 'succsess'
```

@bts_spritesheet_url is obtained from the html5 File Api:

```
handleSpritesheetSelection = (evt) => 
      files = evt.target.files
      f = files[0]
      reader = new FileReader()

      # Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = ((theFile) =>
        return (e) =>   
          @bts_spritesheet_url = e.target
        )(f)
      reader.readAsDataURL(f)
document.getElementById('upload_spritesheet').addEventListener('change', handleSpritesheetSelection, false)
```

The handeler in GAE for a post call to /uploadBTS is:

```
class UploadBTS(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):

    # get information from form post upload
    bts_spriteSheet = self.request.get('bts_spriteSheet') 

    # create database entry for uploaded image 
    bts_entry = Building_Tile_Sets()
    bts_entry.image = db.Blob(bts_spriteSheet)
    bts_entry.put()
```

and lastly the database I'm trying to put the information is a define thus:

```
# Database containg the bts
class Building_Tile_Sets(db.Model):
  image = db.BlobProperty(default=None)
```

I get the following error when trying the upload:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/uploadBTS?bts_spriteSheet=[object%20FileReader]&bts_jason=[object%20Object]&bts_name=one 500 (OK)
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?